# Invalid syntax error when creating series

Tags: numpy, time-series

I am getting a syntax error for this code and I cannot understand why.

```
 # Creating a future data set from 1961 to 65

future_dates = pd.date_range(start= '1961-01-01', end = '1965-01-01', freq = 'MS')

future_df = pd.DataFrame()

future_df['Month'] = [i.month for i in future_dates]

future_df['Year'] = [i.year for i in future_dates]

future_df['Series'] = np.arange(145 (145+len(future_dates)))

future_df.head()
```

Error code:

```
File "<ipython-input-45-40bb268559b0>", line 8 future_df['Series'] = np.arange(145 (145+len(future_dates)))future_df.head() ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: File "<ipython-input-45-40bb268559b0>", line 8
    future_df['Series'] = np.arange(145 (145+len(future_dates)))future_df.head()
                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

You were just missing the comma after 145, not sure what you are trying to doing there. Refer to this : https://realpython.com/how-to-use-numpy-arange/

```
future_df['Series'] = np.arange(145 , (145+len(future_dates)))
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, to give a back drop on why I'm doing this I'm trying to create df for ML model to do some predictions. I was unable to upvote this but will do so once I get the rep points.

Comment: No worries mate. Glad I helped